# Why is my scraping code so slow?

Tags: python, beginner, web-scraping, selenium

I'm a beginner with scraping with Selenium. And I wrote a couple of scrips. And when the script is used for a website with 10-15 pages, it works as it should. However, when I use it on a larger website, like the one in my example below, it takes quite literally more than an hour to execute. Is that normal for this amount of data? Or is there something I should be changing in my code?

For background information, I'm using DigitalOcean, the latest version of Chrome and [this setup,](https://github.com/password123456/setup-selenium-with-chrome-driver-on-ubuntu_debian) with Chrome headless.

This is the code in question, please let me know if you need any more information:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import random
import sqlite3

# Creating and connecting to database
conn = sqlite3.connect('jobs.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Options setup
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

# Scraping
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
base_url = 'https://higher.gs.com/results?&'
driver.get(base_url)

# Number of pages
next_page = 0

jobs = []

for page in range(0, 114):
    driver.get(f"{base_url}page={str(next_page)}&sort=RELEVANCE")
    next_page += 1

    # Get data
    table_rows = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.XPATH, "//*[@data-gs-uitk-component='card-body']"))
    )

    for row in table_rows:
        jobs.append({
            'title': row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.gs-heading').text,
            'info': row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.gs-heading').text,
            'place': row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.gs-text:nth-child(2)').text,
            'link': row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.text-decoration-none').get_attribute('href'),
        })
    time.sleep(random.randint(5, 10))


for job in jobs:
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO jobs(title, info, place, link) VALUES(?,?,?,?)''',
              (job['title'], job['info'], job['place'], job['link']))
conn.commit()


saved_jobs = []
c.execute('''SELECT * FROM jobs''')
for row in c:
    saved_jobs.append({
        'title': row[0],
        'info': row[1],
        'place': row[2],
        'link': row[3]
    })

conn.close()
driver.quit()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Well, you sleep for 5-10s after each page, so times 114 pages this means you are spending somewhere between 9.5 and 19 minutes just waiting.

Comment: Oh, okay! Is that too much waiting time between pages? Should I decrease it, or is standard? I'm applying what I read so far, to avoid being detected. Thank you for your comment, by the way!

Comment: Note that Selenium is ought to be expensive.

Comment: Sleeping is one way to get blocked during web scraping. But it is inherently slow. A faster way is to have multiple proxies and send requests from those without sleep.

Comment: @AjinkyaKamat Got it, thank you for the tip. I'll look into multiple proxies, then!